# Aggregating in pandas groupby using lambda functions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, lambda, group-by

I have an aggregation statement below:

```py
data = data.groupby(['type', 'status', 'name']).agg({
    'one' : np.mean, 
    'two' : lambda value: 100* ((value>32).sum() / reading.mean()), 
    'test2': lambda value: 100* ((value > 45).sum() / value.mean())
})
```

I get KeyErrors. I have been able to make it work for one lambda function but not two.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You need to specify the column in `data` whose values are to be aggregated. 
For example,

```
data = data.groupby(['type', 'status', 'name'])['value'].agg(...)
```

instead of

```
data = data.groupby(['type', 'status', 'name']).agg(...)
```

If you don't mention the column (e.g. `'value'`), then the keys in dict passed to `agg` are taken to be the column names. The `KeyError`s are Pandas' way of telling you that it can't find columns named `one`, `two` or `test2` in the DataFrame `data`.

Note: Passing a dict to `groupby/agg` has been deprecated. Instead, going forward you should pass a list-of-tuples instead. Each tuple is expected to be of the form `('new_column_name', callable)`.

---

Here is runnable example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

N = 100
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'type': np.random.randint(10, size=N),
    'status': np.random.randint(10, size=N),
    'name': np.random.randint(10, size=N),
    'value': np.random.randint(10, size=N),
})

reading = np.random.random(10,)

data = data.groupby(['type', 'status', 'name'])['value'].agg(
    [('one',  np.mean), 
    ('two', lambda value: 100* ((value>32).sum() / reading.mean())), 
    ('test2', lambda value: 100* ((value > 45).sum() / value.mean()))])
print(data)
#                   one  two  test2
# type status name                 
# 0    1      3     3.0    0    0.0
#             7     4.0    0    0.0
#             9     8.0    0    0.0
#      3      1     5.0    0    0.0
#             6     3.0    0    0.0
# ...
```

---

If this does not match your situation, then please provide runnable code that does.

Comment: When I follow the above example, the column names are called <lambda>. Do you know how to add customized names?

Comment: @sometimes24: Are you passing a list of functions to `groupby/agg`? If so, pass a list-of-tuples instead. I've updated the code above to show what I mean. If this is not your situation, then please open a new question with all the details (a runnable example with desired output helps a lot.)

Comment: Is 'reading' value that used lambda function of 'two' column typo?

Answer (score 1):

As @unutbu mentioned, the issue is not with the number of lambda functions but rather with the keys in the dict passed to `agg()` not being in `data` as columns. OP seems to have tried using named aggregation, which assign custom column headers to aggregated columns. A simple way to do it is calling `set_axis()` after aggregation. For example, the following produces the same output as the named aggregation suggested by @unutbu.

```py
data = (
    data.groupby(['type', 'status', 'name'])['value']
    .agg(['mean', lambda value: 100* ((value>32).sum() / reading.mean()), lambda value: 100* ((value > 45).sum() / value.mean())])
    .set_axis(['one', 'two', 'test2'], axis=1)   # <---- rename columns here
)
```

This is especially useful if you want to assign custom names to aggregations involving multiple columns because the `groupby.agg` call can be done normally.

```py
N = 100
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'type': np.random.randint(2, size=N),
    'value1': np.random.randint(50, size=N),
    'value2': np.random.randint(50, size=N)
})
reading = np.random.random(10)

x = (
    data.groupby('type')
    .agg({'value1': [np.mean, lambda value: 100* ((value>32).sum() / reading.mean())],
          'value2': lambda value: 100* ((value > 45).sum() / value.mean())})
    .set_axis(['one', 'two', 'test2'], axis=1)
)


          one          two      test2
type
0    24.00000  2892.413355  18.627451
1    21.44186  1190.993734   4.589114
```

To do the same using named aggregation involves constructing an elaborate dictionary that you pass as kwargs to `groupby.agg()`.

```py
x = (
    data.groupby('type')
    .agg(**{'one': ('value1',  np.mean), 
            'two': ('value1', lambda value: 100* ((value>32).sum() / reading.mean())),
            'test2': ('value2', lambda value: 100* ((value > 45).sum() / value.mean()))})
)

x.equals(y) # True
```